# Can a PrintDialog be modified?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdialog

I am working at a print module and I use a PrintDialog to set the printer settings and then to print. The problem is that I have to do that before **each** print operation.

I want to select the printer settings (all the options provided by PrintDialog) and then to store them somewhere (not to print the document directly from the PrintDialog). Then, when I want to print something, it should print using the stored options.

So my question is the following: can I modify the PrintDialog by changing the name of the "**Print**" button into "**Store Settings**"? Or should I rewrite completely the functionality of that Dialog? (I hope not).

I want to change that button name in order to transform it from a print window into a print settings window.

Also, is there an existing implementation of a similar PrintDialog, other than the default one?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

@CosminIoniță

If I were you I would do this.

Save all the options of the printdialog in a serialized bin file. Read the file the next time and populate all options of the printdialog from there the next time onward.

Hope it helps